# spring boot multiple microservices with one database

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I know there are many questions like this and almost all answers are **No**. And the reason is a single microservice should be independent of another one. And if there is a change in a table, all microservices using that table need to be changed.

But my question is, if my database structure is fixed (hardly there will be any change in the table structure) will it be a good idea of creating multiple microservices pointing to same database.

Okay... here is my project.

We are going to a migrate struts 1.3/EJB 2.0 project to Angular/microservices. This project has 5 different modules and each module is a huge one. And this project is there in production since past 13 years. So there is very little chance of changing the table structures.

The reason I want to make different microservices is, since each modules are huge and complicated, and **we still get requirements to add/change the  business logics**. So in that case, I can deploy only one microservice.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: You will not be making microservices. You will simply be making a distributed monolith.

Comment: Alternatively you can create multiple modules or libraries within your codebase if modularity and separation of concerns is you want to solve. Even if your data structure is fixed, there is a possibility that there is a join across tables and multiple requests from same service try to update same data.

Comment: @im_baby - Okay, [if you are correct] so what do you suggest so I can deploy one module without taking any downtime of other modules?

Comment: Why do the modules need to be separated? Sounds like they just need refactoring maybe. What are their bounded contexts? If they are truly separate domains start by breaking one off and have it own its data. If they are within a single bounded context then keep them that way. 'microservices' doesn't mean a small code base. Just separate bounded contexts.

Comment: @im_baby - I think the OP has made it clear that the different modules are huge and they are getting change requirements from business. However the DB remains same. So it makes sense his/her question (i.e. how to break it apart so they can build and deploy a single module without disturbing the entire project/product.

Comment: Still doesn't explain if the database schema is shared between modules. Why is deploying a single app worse than deploying multiple. The changing business requirements does not make microservices easier than a monolith. Again, if they are overlapping bounded contexts they're not microservices anyways, just a distributed monolith.

Comment: @im_baby - to answer your question 'Why is deploying a single app worse than deploying multiple' - as I said we want to build and deploy one module of the entire project without touching other modules. I don't mind what you call it a 'distributed monolith' or 'microservices ' or anything else. So what is your suggestion ? How we can architect this application?

Comment: My suggestion is to deploy a single application. It will be easier to maintain than 5 deployments which cross boundaries. There hasn't been any reason presented as why this is an issue.

Comment: Ok, never mind. I already explained why we need smaller applications. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a new service that access that database and all other services communicate with this service instead of directly to the database.

If you don't want to create a new service, at least access the DB using some database
abstraction layer.

For example, in SQL server use views and store procedures instead of directly access the tables.

Comment: I read this from an article. But I don't get any example yet. I am upvoting it for now. https://yurynino.medium.com/how-to-use-a-single-mysql-database-in-a-microservices-architecture-484f206220a2